# Multiplication Applet

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception

When attempting a to create a java applet that will help an elementary school student learn multiplication.  Using the Math.random method or a Random object to produce two positive one-digit integers. I am having issues when running the applet. I am fairly new to java programming and this may be a very simple fix.

See below my current code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;



public class NewJApplets extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
public Graphics brush;

Random rand = new Random();
int number1 = rand.nextInt(10);
int number2 = rand.nextInt(10);
JLabel question = new JLabel("What is " + number1 + " times " + number2 + "?");
JLabel Result = new JLabel("");
JTextField answer = new JTextField(3);
JButton checkAnswer = new JButton("Check Answer");
Font font1 = new Font("Teen", Font.BOLD, 30);
Font font2 = new Font("Teen", Font.ITALIC, 36);
String right = "Very good!!!";
String wrong = "No. Please try again.";
Container con = getContentPane();

public void init()
{
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
con.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
question.setLocation(20, 20);
question.setFont(font1);
Result.setLocation (0,100);
Result.setFont(font1);
con.add(question);
con.add(Result);
answer.setLocation(20, 40);

con.add(answer);
checkAnswer.setLocation(20, 60);
con.add(checkAnswer);

checkAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{

public void paint()
{
brush.setFont(font2);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

int ans = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText());

if(ans == number1 * number2)
{
answer.setText("");

Random rand = new Random();


int number1 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
int number2 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
brush.drawString(right, 20, 80);
Result.setText(right);
repaint();
validate();

}

else
{
answer.setText("");
Result.setText(wrong);
brush.drawString(wrong, 80, 20);
repaint();
validate();
}
}
}
);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
answer.setText("");
Random rand = new Random();
int number1 = rand.nextInt(10);
int number2 = rand.nextInt(10);
}
}
```

The applet compiles without any issues, however when attempting to run the applet I am given the following error message.

"**Class does not appear to be an Applet.**" with the options to continue or cancel. After a quick press of continue, I am given the app, which appears to be working. However instead of giving me the proper results I see the output in jGRASP as follows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at NewJApplets$1.actionPerformed(NewJApplets.java:65)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Any help with this issue would be great.

Comment: _NewJApplets.java:65_ - which line is line 65? P.S. please respect java naming conventions - variables should be in lower camel case.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  A frame launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is both easier (for the developer) and a better experience (for the user).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Don't post opinions on teaching applets please. If the content is not helpful to the user, its not worth posting.

Comment: if(ans == number1 * number2) is line 56. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dgrin91  Don't post opinions on what is and is not appropriate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Brush` object is **not initialized**, so you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

You need to add the following line inside your `init()` method:

```
brush=this.getGraphics();
```